# Accessing variables in another file with PHP

Tags: php, variables

How can i obtain variable values from another file in php? I need file to to get the $name value stored in file 1 and store it as a a variable.

file1.php:

```
$name="myname";
echo $name;
```

file2.php:

```
$name=""
```

Comment: include, include_once, require, require_once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of file2.php add this:

```
include ('file1.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use require.

```
require("file1.php");
echo $name; //myname
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sessions.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Script 1:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']="myname";
```

And in Script 2

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Or only include your script:

```
require("file1.php");
```

in your file2.php

Answer (score 0):

File1.php

```
<?php 
$var1 = "Hello World";
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
require("file1.php");
echo $var1; 
?>
```

File2 will print out:
Hello World